# How to create a highchart with 3 different series categories name

Tags: php, jquery, highcharts

I currently new creating a highcart I just want to know if these possible in the highcart. I want to create a cart with 3 categories

**3 Categories:**

1. Low Priority
2. Medium Priority
3. High Priority

So if my categories is 3 so the bar is 3 also with different name and different datas.

**In my console.log the data result shows.**

[image: result]

**My Output:**
[image: wrong output]

**My Function Code:**

```
$.getJSON('ajax/ams_sla_report_chart.php', function(data,name){
    console.log(data);
    var json_data = "";
    var json_name = "";
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'containers',
            type: 'column',
            inverted: false    
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'horizontal',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'middle'
          },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'SLA PERCENTAGE'
            }

        },
        title: {
                text: 'Priority Based on SLA'
        },

        series:[{
            name:'Low Priority',
            colorByPoint: true,
            data:data[0]
        },

        {
            name:'Medium Priority',
            colorByPoint: true,
            data:data[1]
        },


        {
            name:'High Priority',
            colorByPoint: true,
            data:data[2]
        },


        ]
    });


    json_data = chart.series.data = data;



    function showValues() {
    $('#alpha-value').html(chart.options.chart.options3d.alpha);
    $('#beta-value').html(chart.options.chart.options3d.beta);
    $('#depth-value').html(chart.options.chart.options3d.depth);
    }

    // Activate the sliders
    $('#sliders_eng input').on('input change', function () {
        chart.options.chart.options3d[this.id] = parseFloat(this.value);
        showValues();
        chart.redraw(false);
    });

    showValues();


});
```

**Output must be:**

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'SLA BASED ON PRIORITY AND PERCENTAGE OF HIT'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: [
            'Low',
            'Medium',
            'High',
        ],
        crosshair: true
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'SLA BASED ON PERCENTAGE (mm)'
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
        pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
            '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y}</b></td></tr>',
        footerFormat: '</table>',
        shared: true,
        useHTML: true
    },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            pointPadding: 0.2,
            borderWidth: 0
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'CLOSE MR',
        data: [49.9, 71.5, 106.4]

    }, {
        name: 'OPEN MR',
        data: [83.6, 78.8, 98.5]

    }, {
        name: 'TOTAL MR HIT',
        data: [48.9, 38.8, 39.3]

    }, {
        name: 'TOTAL MR HIT AVERAGE',
        data: [50, 38.8, 39.3]

    }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Comment: Hi @DevGe, Could you create some live example with hard-coded data? I know that you want to have 3 categories, but I do not know how you want to arrange the data.

Comment: sure i will give the example @ppotaczek thanks.

Comment: hi @ppotaczek i update my post

Comment: Thanks, but now your JSON data is different from what you showed on the chart.: `[['Low Priority', 100, 9], ['Medium Priority', 100, 2], ['High Priority', 100, 1]]`

Comment: @ppotaczek yah you''re right, so is it possible to push the data to make the output like that

Comment: Please check this example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/xu6wy910/ and let me know if that's what you wanted.

Comment: @ppotaczek exactly sorry for late reply.

Comment: @ppotaczek how can i add more categories?

Comment: Just add another element in the `data` array: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/u1co2xe4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to preprocess your data to the format required by Highcharts:

```
var data = [
        ['Low Priority', 100, 9],
        ['Medium Priority', 100, 2],
        ['High Priority', 100, 1]
    ],
    categories = [],
    series = [];

data.forEach(function(arr) {
    arr.forEach(function(el, i) {
        if (i === 0) {
            categories.push(el);
        } else if (series[i - 1]) {
            series[i - 1].data.push(el)
        } else {
            series.push({
                data: [el]
            });
        }
    });
});


Highcharts.chart('container', {
    ...
    series: series
});
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/xu6wy910/

Comment: is it possible to customize the series name? because each element value has own different name.

Comment: Hi @DevGe, Yes, you can also put the series name in the array: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/tb9co0qf/